# HTML5 / WebSocket / WebRTC redirection over RDP

Tags: webrtc, html5-audio, remote-desktop

Does anybody know what Microsoft / Citrix / VMWare use to achieve redirecting WebRTC traffic from apps such as MS Teams and HTML 5 Video over RDP. From what i can see there is no open soruce version of these.

I am currently looking to redirect MS Teams Multimedia such as Audio and Video so they connect using the local client and can see the major players have achieved this. I can see that Citrix and Microsoft use their own WebSocket server then redirect the traffic over a virtual channel to the local client and then use this to create the media connection between peers.

I understand how to create Virtual channels and transmit data over them but i can not see any documentation on Microsoft's sites that shows how they redirect the traffic from the app.

I would also love to be able to redirect multimedia from sites such as youtube to play on the local client and forward over the video, i can see this has been done my Citrix and VMWare but am unable to find any documentation on how to achieve this.

Any information on how to achieve this would be great, I will be doing the code in mostly .Net due to the ease of creating the RDP plugin.

Thanks

Chris